# How do I get a list of views back programatically in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I found this tutorial but it is in Vb and missing too much stuff so I am unsure how to get it to work.

```
Here is a short example of how to get list views using Client object model in SharePoint 2010



Dim objmyList As SP.List = g_objCore.Security.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(“**Your List Name*”)

Dim objmyView As SP.View = objmyList.Views.GetByTitle(“*Your View Name*”)

Dim objViewFldColl As SP.ViewFieldCollection = objmyView.ViewFields

g_objCore.Security.ClientContext.Load(objViewFldColl)

g_objCore.Security.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()

Now you can iterate through objViewFldColl to get the Fields in the View
```

I am unsure how to get this client object model. I also don't know what List to import in. I get a choice of like 3 namespaces

```
using Microsoft.Office.Server.ActivityFeed;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.Audience.AdminUI;
using System.Windows.Documents;
```

I am trying to make this in a visual web part code behind. I am using C# and I literally have 5minutes of share point experience(sort of have to skip the 101 of sharepoint and do this little part of some project that I am now on temporary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at client side OM (to be used from browser code or client applications). For code behind in Web part you should be using server OM: SPList.Views - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.views.aspx.

Something like `SPContext.CurrentWeb.Lists[0].Views`...